# Issue with MediaPlayer used in a static context (ARCore)

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore

I am using Google's ARCore library to create an app to detect an image, play a video for that specific image, and then stop that video when a new image is detected. The logic of the image detection is working properly, the issue I have been having is with the android MediaPlayer class, and stopping the video when a new image is detected.

I define a separate class for the MediaPlayer object that will be referenced (Singleton pattern). This class will be used to start and stop the MediaPlayer.

```
public class AugmentedImageMediaPlayer {

public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayerInstance = new MediaPlayer();

public static void startMediaPlayer(Context context, int augmentedImageIndex, Surface surface, boolean isLooping){
    mediaPlayerInstance = MediaPlayer.create(context, AugmentedImageFragment.videoList[augmentedImageIndex]);
    mediaPlayerInstance.setSurface(surface);
    mediaPlayerInstance.setLooping(isLooping);
}

public static void stopMediaPlayer(){
    if(mediaPlayerInstance.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayerInstance.stop();
    }
}
```

}

When a new image is detected, a node is created, and a MediaPlayer object is created from the class above (AugmentedImageMediaPlayer). The MediaPlayer is played on a surface and set as the renderable on a node.

```
AugmentedImageMediaPlayer.startMediaPlayer(context, augmentedImageIndex, texture.getSurface(), false);

// Set the anchor based on the center of the image.
setAnchor(image.createAnchor(image.getCenterPose()));


//TODO: Video nodes here.
Node videoNode = new Node();
videoNode.setParent(this);


float videoWidth = AugmentedImageMediaPlayer.mediaPlayerInstance.getVideoWidth();
float videoHeight = AugmentedImageMediaPlayer.mediaPlayerInstance.getVideoHeight();
videoNode.setLocalScale(
        new Vector3(
                VIDEO_HEIGHT_METERS * (videoWidth / videoHeight), VIDEO_HEIGHT_METERS, 1.0f));

Quaternion q1 = videoNode.getLocalRotation();
Quaternion q2 = Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(1.0f, 0f, 0f), 90f);
videoNode.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.multiply(q1, q2));

if (!AugmentedImageMediaPlayer.mediaPlayerInstance.isPlaying()) {
  AugmentedImageMediaPlayer.mediaPlayerInstance.start();

  // Wait to set the renderable until the first frame of the  video becomes available.
  // This prevents the renderable from briefly appearing as a black quad before the video
  // plays.
  texture
          .getSurfaceTexture()
          .setOnFrameAvailableListener(
                  (SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) -> {
                    videoNode.setRenderable(videoPlacedRenderable);
                    texture.getSurfaceTexture().setOnFrameAvailableListener(null);
                  });

  // this stops the video from playingAugmentedImageMediaPlayer.mediaPlayerInstance.stop();
} else {
  videoNode.setRenderable(videoPlacedRenderable);
}
```

All of this works correctly, and the video starts perfectly fine. The issue is is that I can't stop the video outside of the node (can stop it in the node's class), even though I defined a class to make sure that the MediaPlayer can be referenced and changed.

This is where I am trying to stop the video:

```
node = new AugmentedImageNode(this);
        node.setImage(augmentedImage, this, this.augmentedImageIndex);
        augmentedImageMap.put(augmentedImage, node);
        arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(node);
        AugmentedImageMediaPlayer.stopMediaPlayer();
```

Any help with how I might switch this around to make it possible to stop or if I am completely missing something obvious would be wonderful. Thank you.

Comment: Any help would be wonderful.